# Why is there no EventHandler<TSender, TEventArgs> delegate in the BCL?

Tags: .net, event-handling

Just curious to know why a delegate of the form

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TSender, TEventArgs>(
       TSender sender, 
       TEventArgs e
) 
where TEventArgs : EventArgs;
```

doesn't exist in the framework. Is there a reason why only the following is provided?

```
public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(
     object sender,
     TEventArgs e
)
where TEventArgs : EventArgs;
```

Comment: Because `sender` is always of type `object`. A generic type is not needed or allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your "why" question is not easy — for who knows except them why Microsoft's BCL engineers decided on this and not another way? — but I'll make an educated guess:

> ```
> public delegate void EventHandler<TEventArgs>(
>     Object sender,
>     TEventArgs e
> )
> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
> ```

I could imagine that this delegate type was added to the .NET BCL as an "afterthought". Remember that .NET 1.0 did not have generics.

Another reasoning is that quite often, an event handler handles events for one sender only, so inside that handler you already know about the sender without even having to look at the `sender` argument, so why make the delegate more generic than it needs to be for most practical purposes.

You're usually much more interested in the event arguments `e` than in the sender, so it makes sense to avoid an unnecessary type cast there by making it generic.

Comment: Often the sender gets cast back on the subscriber side as well which could have easily been avoided using a more generic delegate. Clearly when they added EventHandler<TEventArgs> they had an option to add EventHandler<TSender, TEventArgs> as well but I guess they deliberately skipped this. The "why" of my question is related to this - can there be a problem in using this delegate?

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: I gave some possible reasons why the `TSender` type paramater could have been omitted, but I can think of no technical necessity that *requires* its absence... except *perhaps* that type inference / co-/contravariance works better when there's only one type parameter...? In the end, I guess it was simply a decision made by the .NET BCL guys. If you absolutely must know the "why", ask them -- though let me ask you, is it really worth the effort? What will you gain from it?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this. As mentioned in the question, i was just curious to know the design choice and if I was missing an obvious argument in favour of this.